# If 2 is a unit in a ring R, then there exists a bijection between the idempotents of the ring and the self-inverse elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring with unity $1_R$, and suppose $2=1_R+1_R$ is a unit. I am asked to show that the map $\sigma: \{e:e^{2}=e\} \rightarrow \{u:u^{2}=1\},$ $\sigma(e)=1-2e$ is a bijection. Here is my attempt: First, the map is well-defined since if $e$ is an idempotent, $(1-2e)^{2}=1-4e+4e^{2}=1-4e+4e=1$, so the image of any idempotent under $\sigma$ is indeed self-inverse. Injectivity is clear. To show surjectivity, suppose $u\in R$ with $u^{2}=1$. Consider the element $2^{-1}(1-u)$. $1-2(2^{-1}(1-u))=1-(1-u)=u$, so if we can show $2^{-1}(1-u)$ is an idempotent, we're done. To establish this, note first that since $u$ commutes with $2$ it must also commute with $2^{-1}$. Hence we may write $(2^{-1}(1-u))^{2}=(2^{-1})^{2}(1-u)^{2}=(2^{-1})^{2}(1-2u+u^{2})=(2^{-1})^{2}(2-2u)=2^{-1}(1-u)$, as desired. Is my proof correct? I welcome any comments or criticism.

Comment: It looks fine.  I would avoid saying that something "is clear".  If it's easy, just give the proof.  In this case, injectivity requires using the invertibility of $2$ (the only condition of the problem) so it's worth spelling it out.

Comment: Also, use paragraphs!

Comment: I think it looks fine. I think the clear stuff really is clear and would leave it. This is a matter of audience.

Comment: Why does $u$ commute with $2$?

Comment: $u$ commutes with $2$ since $2u=(1_R+1_R)u=u+u=u(1_R+1_R)$.

Comment: Ah.  I see.  Easy enough.

Comment: @Randall I think that "injectivity follows from the invertibility of $2$" is just as easy to write as "injectivity is clear" and is much more informative regarding the structure of the proof.  There's no purpose in obscuring where the conditions are used.

Comment: @Slade I'll agree to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the map is well-defined since if $e$ is an idempotent, $(1-2e)^{2}=1-4e+4e^{2}=1-4e+4e=1$, so the image of any idempotent under $\sigma$ is indeed self-inverse.

Hm?  That doesn't say anything about the rule being well-defined. It just simply confirms that the relation's codomain lies in the set of self-inverse elements. Useful, but it is not "why the map is well-defined."

To say that it is well-defined, you'd need to start with $e=f$ and conclude that $1-2e=1-2f$. Fortunately, this is easy. You can just say  "the rule $e\mapsto 1-2e$ defines a function since it is the composition of functions $e\mapsto 2e$ and $e\mapsto 1-e$."

That the latter two things are functions are inherent in the definition of binary operations of a ring, so there is no question about that.

Otherwise, I think you have covered all the bases well.

Comment: Sorry, initially I misinterpreted the adjectives on something and had a different problem a few minutes ago. After re-reading, I changed my mind about the problem I was seeing.

Comment: I see, I think I was confused about what "well-defined" meant here. What I wanted to do was emphasize that it may not be immediately apparent that $1-2e$ is its own inverse.